# Replacing a ceiling lamp LED. Has 2 switches at either end. Black wire hot no matter switch position. Need Help

Tags: electrical, switch, repair, light

Replacing a ceiling lamp LED. Has 2 switches at either end. The black wire is hot no matter the switch position. Need Help. I am using a non conductive probe. I can shut the power off by a breaker but was worried this was wired incorrectly. Kitchen has two 3-way switches at either end. The light went out, decided to get a new one. While getting the light off the ceiling noticed that with the breaker on the black wire was hot no matter what the position of the switches [both up, both down, opposite x2] Been years since working on a house again [I normally do DC on computers and cars, electronics and such.] My father and brother are both passed or I would have asked them. Just moved and have no friends either, so I am here, thanks.

Comment: Never trust a switch to turn off the power, always use the breaker.  A switch only breaks one wire, so power is off on only half of that wire.

Comment: Three way switches(two switches for light) confuse me unless I have a diagram/picture I can see.  A black wire that is hot in a ceiling fixture might just be from the breaker to power the light.  No switch will turn that off.

Comment: There are several ways to wire a 3-way switch. In an older home, it's not uncommon for the power to be supplied to the fixture box and then cables (switch legs in electrician parlance) to the 3-way switches.  I don't like that method, but it was commonly done in the past before smart switches needed a neutral.   Anyway, hopefully you didn't disconnect a bunch of wires and can simply put up the new fixture using the old connections, it should be fine. If you took it all apart, you have some detective work to do.

Comment: Was the light correctly controlled by the two switches before you started monkeying around with it?

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri " user156117 is a new contributor. Be nice, and check out our Code of Conduct."

Answer (score 1):

Non contact voltage probes and multimeters will lie to you. This is an effect called phantom voltage.

Connect a real load (like the lamp)

Answer (score 0):

It is common to find always Hot in the ceiling box.

From there it goes to one for the 3 way.

That one passes it on to the second 3 way using wires called travelers.

That second 3 way sends it up back to the ceiling light and depending on the switch position, you can on/off the light from any switch.

Here is a example of the wiring (not yours)

[image: always hot]

Open the switch boxes, and find the always hot. Look at the colors of the wires. One is probably black (or even white) and the other 2 are ? what color.

Now find those 2 colors on the other switch.